# Difference between ECMAScript6 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript

As funny as it sounds I recently learned about ECMAScript and I know that JavaScript is based on ECMAScript. On Mozilla website it says that:

"**ECMAScript 2015(6) is the current version of the ECMAScript Language Specification standard.(June 17, 2015)**"

Also I read about the **Arrow Functions** and **constants**, but I can't use them in JavaScript ->

- Are these only for ES6?
- Should I stick to JavaScript or start learning ES6?

Comment: This is a little broad for SO.. You can experiment with Babel: https://babeljs.io/repl/ But any javascript you learn will serve you well - ES6 has some additions, but much of the language remains the same.

Comment: ECMAScript comes in different flavors. There's JScript, ActionScript, SpiderMonkey, [etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Implementations). JavaScript is just one syntax for ECMAScript. ES6 is the newest standard. Not all engines support it yet.

Comment: Chrome's V8 engine supports ES6 style JavaScript, if you're looking for a playground. It's the same engine that node.js uses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript has had many names over the years and it is really just an implementation of ECMAscript.

It is a great idea to learn ES6 especially if you are doing any kind of web development.

Arrow functions and constants were introduced in ES6 and not everything that supports es5 supports es6 functionality. See [this](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) for an exhaustive list

So should you learn JS or start learning ES6? Either/both will serve you well. Personally I think the new features in ES6 may not be fully graspable until you learn the basic tenets of JS and you understand WHY they were introduced in ES6

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already know JS that is why I was asking if I should switch to ES6. I like to learn new things, so I will give it a try.

Comment: absolutely learn es6. however, if you want to write a production ready app using es6 features and have it run everywhere you will need to employ a transpiler so older browsers etc can run your code in a version of js they are familiar with